# Solving for x in $\frac{1+y}{1-y}=(1+x)^{1+x}(1-x)^{1-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How can I solve for x?
> $$\frac{1+y}{1-y}=(1+x)^{1+x}(1-x)^{1-x}$$

I have tried a few methods, but to be honest, I do not think I have what it takes to find the solutions. I'm hoping someone has has experience with these sorts of equations and can help me out!

Comment: Is this a Diophantine equation? or are you just looking to isolate a variable?

Comment: FWIW:  We know that $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Not a Diophantine equation. I want to find all possible solutions (x,y) that satisfy the equation. Or at least find some limitations as to what they can be.

Comment: FWIW: I'm not sure what approach you would use, but at least I can confirm there *is* an answer. I plugged this into Mathematica and it was able to give as many instances of $y,x$ pairs as I wanted that satisfy it. Looks like they're probably all complex.

Comment: Please, do not change the post after answers have been provided. This makes the problem confusing. In any manner, what I made is still valid (except for the examples). Replace $k$

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm new here!

Answer (score 3):

Let ${y+1\over y-1}=M$

Then $M-1={2\over y-1}\implies y={2\over M-1}+1$ or $y={M+1\over M-1}={(1+x)^{1+x}(1-x)^{1-x}+1 \over (1+x)^{1+x}(1-x)^{1-x}-1}$

Comment: I think the question asks for *actual numerical values* for $x$ and $y$.  Which is why person is asking whether this is a Diophantine equation.

Comment: May be so, the question is not that clear with it's purpose.

Comment: If so, please do not attempt to answer the question before the asker clarifies their intent.

Comment: Should I delete it now ?

Comment: Not a Diophantine equation.

Comment: This gives you exactly what you asked for in your comment @Bean The solutions are $\left(x,{(1+x)^{1+x}(1-x)^{1-x}+1 \over (1+x)^{1+x}(1-x)^{1-x}-1}\right)$

Comment: Yes, this is helpful, thank you!

Comment: But what if I want to now solve for x in terms of y?

Comment: Just looking at the equation, its probably not possibly without special functions. Maybe someone can show otherwise

Answer (score 2):

IfI properly understand, what you are asked is for find, for a given value of $y$ the corresponding $x$.

This equation is very highly transcendental and you will need some numerical method and, for sure, a "reasonable" guess of the solution.

To some extent, this problem is a red herring and, to me, the worst thing to do would be to write $y=f(x)$.

For a given $y$, you know the value of $\left(\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right)$. So, to make the problem much nicer, define $k=\log \left(\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right)$ and, taking logarithms, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$g(x)=(1+x) \log (1+x)+(1-x) \log (1-x)-k$$ which is quite nice and very smooth (almost looking like a parabola).

Expanding the rhs as an infinite series
$$k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2 n}}{n (2 n-1)}$$ Using series reversion
$$x=\sqrt k \,\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n k^n$$ The $a_n$'s make the sequence
$$\left\{1,-\frac{1}{12},-\frac{13}{1440},-\frac{97}{40320},-\frac{25307}{29030400},-\frac{56827}{153280512},\cdots\right\}$$ and this is almost the exact solution.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will see where I can go with it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to solve for $y$ (and not have a particular value, which I think there are multiple valid values), then it is pretty straightforward.  Multiply both sides by $y - 1$.  Then, collect all of the $y$ terms to one side.  Then, pull out the $y$ term.  Finally, divide by the rest to isolate $y$ by itself.

Comment: I am trying to solve for both x and y.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't a single answer.  If you plot it, you can see it has solutions roughly between -1 and 1.  If you just want individual solutions, you can just substitute some values between -1 and 1 in for x, and then solve for y.  For instance, I found for $x = 0.5$, $y = 7.68811\ldots$.

Comment: Is it possible to solve for x in terms of y?

Comment: The function's curve only goes from $(-1,-4)$ to $(1,4)$.